# When is the resurrection of Old Testament saints (from Moses to John the baptist)?

Tags: old-testament, saint, resurrection

When is the resurrection  of Old Testament saints (from Moses to John the baptist)?

Comment: The answer will vary greatly from denomination to denomination. The question needs to specify whose point of view you want. ¶ A literal Bible answer is that there will be a resurrection of saints when Jesus returns (the first resurrection) and a second resurrection of everyone else at the end of the Millennium (the second resurrection), as described in Revelation 20. But this is interpreted in many different non-literal ways.